# Why do I need Apache HTTPD?

Tags: apache, http, tcp

I'm trying to learn about servers but there's something that I just don't understand, which is:
If your server has TCP on it, then why do you need Apache HTTPD?

I'm still pretty new to this but I've learned that TCP is basically what servers and routers use to handle requests using different protocols like http, ftp and ssh.

So if TCP already handles http, then what do i need Apache HTTPD for?

I've tried to find an answer but all I'm told is that I need Apache HTTPD because otherwise I just cant connect to the server using http?

Comment: TCP is layer 3 and HTTP is layer 4.  See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786900(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: TCP is just a "transport" protocol.  There is also UDP.  TCP and UDP just transport data back and forth.  They don't know what they are transporting.  Other things use TCP also, like FTP.  It's up to the application (in this case Apache) to handle the *actual* data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are talking about, TCP and Apache, operate on two different layers of the transport model.  This article has a very length, in-depth breakdown of it: [Wikipedia - Internet protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)

**TL;DR** - TCP is the *transmission protocol* used by Apache to communicate with the computers making requests of it.  Think of TCP as the language Apache speaks.

The pertinent parts to your question are the Abstraction Layers:

> - The Application layer is the scope within which applications create user data and communicate this data to other applications on another or the same host. The applications, or processes, make use of the services provided by the underlying, lower layers, especially the Transport Layer which provides reliable or unreliable pipes to other processes. The communications partners are characterized by the application architecture, such as the client-server model and peer-to-peer networking. This is the layer in which all higher level protocols, such as SMTP, FTP, SSH, HTTP, operate. Processes are addressed via ports which essentially represent services.
> - The Transport Layer performs host-to-host communications on either the same or different hosts and on either the local network or remote networks separated by routers. It provides a channel for the communication needs of applications. UDP is the basic transport layer protocol, providing an unreliable datagram service. The Transmission Control Protocol provides flow-control, connection establishment, and reliable transmission of data.

Here's a graphic representation:
[image: Network Topology Diagram]

In this graphic, Apache is an Application, and TCP is the Transport.